# How to measure ratings of a transformer?

Tags: transformer, measurement, maximum-ratings

If I am given a transformer without any datasheet of it. Then how can I measure the maximum current and voltage rating of the transformer?

Comment: There is no explicit test for these besides destructive testing. Push power through it til it pops or find a part number.

Comment: You must be fun in the lab!

Comment: Possible you could try and see where it saturates, this might give some clue?

Comment: How can I find where it saturates?

Comment: The problem with this is max current, which is largely going to depend on when the core overheats. With a good power source, a load bank and a thermocouple you could actually make a guess at what the rated temp rise is, and then find the load that causes that. But it's guesswork. If possible, it makes more sense to open the thing and measure the conductor size, then check the tables. This may be impractical. I'd have been less negative if I thought you wanted approximations - but still, nothing will tell you exactly what the manufacturer set as max current.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know some basic specs for the transformer before you can start.  In particular, you need to have some idea of the intended frequency if it is a power transformer.

I would start by measuring the DC resistance of all the windings.  If you are given a transformer with many leads and no other information, these DC resistance measurements will also tell you which leads belong to each winding.

Start with the winding that has the highest DC resistance.  Feed in a low-voltage signal at the frequency that the transformer is designed to operate at.  Measure the voltage out of all of the other windings - you want to get an idea of the turns ratio of each winding.

Now it becomes a tiny bit more complicated.  But not much.

You want to increase the signal amplitude into that winding to find out where the core begins to saturate.  How you do this depends on the transformer, whether it is designed for AC Mains operation (50 / 60 Hz) or some other frequency.

If the transformer is designed to operate from the AC Mains, connect a small (60 Watt) light bulb in series with a Variac and drive the winding.  Either monitor the AC waveform using an oscilloscope or simply increase the input AC voltage until the bulb brigtness begins to increase significantly.  The onset of saturation is usually quite well defined.

That tells you the maximum voltage that this winding can tolerate.

Got to go - will return.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the conductor size you can ballpark the rating .This means the RMS current that can be handled .Note that the permissable current density which could be expressed in amps per mm squared isnt quite constant with conductor size .Bigger transformers will run lower permissable current density and smaller transformers can run higher current density.The maths of this assumes no forced cooling and no cooling flutes and neglible core loss.You end up with something to the power of a quarter instead of zero .In other words it all boils down to surface area to volume ratio .I f people still dont get it I say that you wont see a Eskimo that looks like me!Now that you have ballparked it you can measure the room temp DCR of the windings  and load up the transformer if you know the rated input volts .After warming it up you can remeasure the winding DCR and deduce the temp to get the current rating .Remember DCR isnt exactly proportional to absolute temp like George OHM said .There are tables that take into account the higher order terms that are significant at our expected temps .Also remember that the transformer wire heats with RMS currents so for example a cap input filter will heat the wire more than a resistor of equal power,If you dont know the input volts the variac like Dwayne Reid said is safe.